# Filling only selected columns with data and appending the remaning with NaN values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = [column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4] )

sample_data = [(78, 89), (77, 45), (54, 90)]
```

I want to insert the `sample_data` in the `sample_dataframe` in a way that `column_1` and `column_2` will get filled with values from the data and the remaining columns will be filled with NaN values for all the rows.

I cannot add the data to the dataframe while it's creation. The data needs to be added later after defining the structure for the dataframe.

What is the easiest way to do this?

This is the output I want :

```
> sample_dataframe

column1 column2 column3 column4
78      89      NaN     NaN
77      45      NaN     NaN
54      90      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Just assign them: `sample_dataframe[["column1", "column2"]] = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid problems with the indices, you could use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to update on a subset of columns. You can assign either a newly created dataframe:

```
cols = ['column_1', 'column_2']
sample_dataframe.assign(**pd.DataFrame(sample_data, columns=cols))

   column_1  column_2 column_3 column_4
0        78        89      NaN      NaN
1        77        45      NaN      NaN
2        54        90      NaN      NaN
```

Or by unpacking a dictionary:

```
sample_dataframe.assign(**dict(zip(cols,zip(*sample_data))))
```